# Please help how to show that $x_{n_k}$ is convergent

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, normed-spaces

In a  normed linear space $X$ if  every absolutely convergent series is convergent then prove that the space is a Banach Space.

**My try**:

Let $x_n$ be a  Cauchy Sequence in $X$ 
.Then we can find a subsequence $n_k$ such that $||x_{n_{k+1}}-x_{n_k}||<\dfrac{1}{2^k}$.

Define $y_k=x_{n_{k+1}}-x_{n_k}$ and form the series $\sum y_k$. Then $\sum y_k$ is absolutely convergent and hence convergent. So $\lim_{n\to \infty} y_k=0$.

But I have to find a convergent subsequence of $x_n$ .I tried showing that $x_{n_k}$ is convergent but i failed.

Please help how to show that $x_{n_k}$ is convergent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serie $\sum y_k$ is absolutely convergent so by hypothesis it is convergent.
So $\sum x_{n_{k+1}}-x_{n_k}$ is convergent , we will name S this limit. We name Sj the partial sums.$$S_j=\sum_{k=1}^jx_{n_{k+1}}-x_{n_k}=x_{n_{j}}-x_{n_1}$$
So $\lim_{j\to \infty} x_{n_{j}}=x_{n_1}+S$
Finally $x_{n_k}$ is convergent.